# No memory left on ascari causes Hudson build failed?

Tags: svn, hudson, hudson-plugins, sonarqube

Does anyone ever experience random Hudson server crash? See the following log:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "env": java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.getSystemEnvVars(CommandLineUtils.java:250)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.getSystemEnvVars(CommandLineUtils.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.project.interpolation.RegexBasedModelInterpolator.<init>(RegexBasedModelInterpolator.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor120.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.java.JavaComponentFactory.newInstance(JavaComponentFactory.java:44)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.createComponentInstance(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1464)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:93)
```

It is now installed on 32 bit Debian 5 Linux with 4 GB RAM along with SVN and Sonar, I'd like to know what would be the root cause of this problem ? I'm planning to migrate it to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bit with SVN and Sonar as well, but this time I'll give 8 GB for the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

4GB of RAM seems enough to run Hudson, but it seems you are running out of memory due to too many processes.

Try increase your **swap partition** size.

Your swap partition should generally be the size of your RAM, if not more.

PS: What is it currently at?

Comment: it is currently at 2 GB and i have created script to restart the service every 11 PM to prevent this error.

Comment: If you can, try to increase your swap to at least 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, my server config is:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1036        982         53          0         13         39
-/+ buffers/cache:        929        106
Swap:         2047        833       1214
```

This is how I fixed the problem (under `root`):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Comment: Hi, is that 32 / 64 bit server ?